# Partitioned Indexes Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

Can I make global partitioned index with TRUNC on column ? Smth like:

```
    CREATE INDEX "SCHEMA"."IND_DATA_TEST" ON "SCHEMA"."TEST_TABLE" (TRUNC("DATA"), "TEST_COLUMN") 
  GLOBAL PARTITION BY RANGE (TRUNC("DATA"))
 (PARTITION "PRT_06_06"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2006-06-01', 'SYYYY-MM-DD', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) TABLESPACE "TEST_A_IND" , 
  PARTITION "PRT_06_07"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2006-07-01', 'SYYYY-MM-DD', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) TABLESPACE "TEST_A_IND" , 
 PARTITION "PRT_OTH"  VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) TABLESPACE "TEST_A_IND" ) 
  PARALLEL 8 ;
```

Comment: `RANGE (TRUNC(DATA))` is useless, simply use `RANGE (DATA)`. You specify full days for ranges, so it does not make any difference.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Usually you make either `LOCAL` indexes or (one) `GLOBAL` index. Using `GLOBAL PARTITION` meas you partitionize the index but the partitions of index are different than on underlying table. You must have very special circumstances to justify this.

Comment: When I create that index without TRUNC("DATA") and I use that column in select shmth like "select * from TEST_TABLE where TRUNC("DATA") > ......" that index is never used.

Answer (score 0):

You can, defining a virtual column in place of your "trunc(data)". This is possible because oracle supports

- indexes on virtual columns
- partitions on virtual columns

However check with your version of Oracle, because either or both features may not be supported in your version.

Write code along the lines of:

```
drop table xxx_demo;

create table xxx_demo (
  date_field date,
  sample_field number,
  truncated_field as (trunc(date_field)) --this is the virtual column
)
;

create index partitioned_index
on xxx_demo(truncated_field, sample_field)
GLOBAL
partition by range(truncated_field)(
PARTITION "PRT_06_06"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2006-06-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')), 
PARTITION "PRT_OTH"  VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) 
)
;
```

You can see that your index is actually used when accessing the table by the right query

```
insert into xxx_demo(date_field, sample_field) values(sysdate, 1);
insert into xxx_demo(date_field, sample_field) values(sysdate-365*20, 2);

explain plan for
select * from xxx_demo where truncated_field < sysdate-365;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 2789338220

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                   |     1 |    31 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR    |                   |     1 |    31 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |   KEY |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| XXX_DEMO          |     1 |    31 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | PARTITIONED_INDEX |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |   KEY |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("TRUNCATED_FIELD"<SYSDATE@!-365)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of parallel threshold
```